# Star * symbol in git prompt on zsh

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh

**Terminal:** iTerm2

**Shell:** zsh (oh my zsh)

**Issue:** I am seeing a star * on git prompt even though the branch has been updated and no changes have been made. Any idea what it means and how to get it cleared from the git prompt.

[image: See Image]

Comment: What does “git status” show?

Comment: Here is the output:

❯ git status

On branch develop

Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.


nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: [tag:iterm2] is not actually relevant: the prompt setting works in other terminal emulators.

Answer (score 25):

The * indicates that you have x number of stashes saved on this repository. So  in your case `*1` means that you have 1 stash stored on this repository. Run below command and you will see that this number matches the number of stashes:

`git stash list`

If `*1` bothers you then you can remove† your stashes with:

`git stash clear`

†: this will permanently delete your stashes and you will not be able to recover them through the normal safety mechanisms‡.

‡: Reference - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-Recoveringstashentriesthatwerecleareddroppederroneously

Comment: Spent almost 30mins on this, you're a life saver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The official [git-prompt.sh script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e391989789db82983665667013a46eabc6fc570/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L38-L42) includes:

```sh
# In addition, if you set GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE to a nonempty value,
# unstaged (*) and staged (+) changes will be shown next to the branch
# name.  You can configure this per-repository with the
# bash.showDirtyState variable, which defaults to true once
# GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE is enabled.
```

Check first in your `~/.zshrc` if you are using [`vcs_info` instead](https://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/customize-zsh-prompt-with-vcs-info.html).
It could come with its own set of customization, as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mika/e30b4e99c338f5d80d7681407708609b).

For instance, check with `git stash list` if you have any files stashed.